# predicting the image classification

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning

i trained a neural network on matlab using googlenet, and i exported the .mat file model to python using the code below. but when i try to predict the image it says dictionary has no attribute predict. so how to predict the input image when a NN model is exported to python

i tried the following code for prediction :

```
prediction = annots.predict([image])
prediction = list(prediction[0])
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))])
```

.mat to python code:

```
import scipy
from scipy.io import loadmat
annots = loadmat('Anet.mat')
image = "1.jpg" #your image path
print(type(annots))
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\prajw\OneDrive\Desktop\pi3", line 7, in <module>
prediction = annots.predict([image])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'predict'
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is not so simple. loadmat cannot load a saved network because it is not a matrix or a structure. It is an object with functions that loadmat cannot access. You can try exporting the net to ONNX format. Alternatively, you can build the architecture with python, then read the weights from .mat files that you save, containing the weights only, not the whole network.

Comment: yeah ONNX worked!!! Thanks.